# Why does certbot generate Nginx config a test for server_name?

Tags: nginx, certbot

```
server {
    if ($host = test.google.ca) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name test.google.ca;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Why is it that certbot generates a server block that looks like this? Is a test for the server_name required?

Comment: You don't have to use the `--nginx` with certbot.  I personally don't like to have it manage (usually mangle) my web server config.  I prefer to use the `--webroot --webroot-path [path/to/webroot]` option or have it use [dns challenge](https://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-01-challenge-validation) that doesn't change the config.